# Google Data API .NET library compile in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I compile the Google Data API .NET library in WP7 . I know that I have to download the source code and compile it as a Windows Phone Library. But not sure about how to compile it. I m getting lots of errors while trying to compile the code as Windows Phone 7 Library. If somebody has already tried it successfully please help me out.

Comment: Which API (There's several). And if you get errors, then you should try **read** the errors. they usually tell you what's wrong.

Comment: yes, more information would be helpful. what kind of error's, Maybe event the link to were you got the Google library's. Something is always better then nothing. :)

Comment: I  got the source code from the following link http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list the file name is libgoogle-data-mono-1.9.0.0.tar.gz file and tried to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any kind of port of Google APIs to WP7. There is a .net implementation but as far as I know is on ALPHA stage.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/

To use that on a WP7 client you need to create a windows phone class lib project and port those classes that you need. You need to pay attention because WP framework is limited comparing to .net framework.

Hope that it helps,